# Acceptability of Gonna, Wanna

Tags: formality

How acceptable is it to use wanna, gonna, etc in business or more formal US environments?

Comment: Verbally or in writing?

Comment: @RdeoNYC Another place you might get answers is this StackExchange site: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's entirely inappropriate. Always.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. If you are writing/typing something, then it is definitely not appropriate. In business settings, people must act professional, which means using proper English. Similarly, if you are speaking but delivering a presentation of some kind, they're not appropriate.

If you're speaking to a colleague or in a colloquial/friendly context, "wanna" and "gonna" are okay. But, alternatively, if you are speaking to someone in a much higher position than you, it's probably best to use "want to" or "going to" (depending on the person).