# "wanna" at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, contractions

I'm not a native speaker. A pupil wrote "wanna" at the end of a sentence:

> You can go if you wanna.

It sounds odd to me, as if something had to follow wanna (as opposed to want to/ want, which can stand alone)?

Please note that this question is not asking about the acceptability of 'wanna' as a written 'analogue' of 'want to' in general. That has already been thoroughly covered in other questions, notably in various answers at [kinda sorta coulda shoulda lotta oughta betcha tseasy etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296051/kinda-sorta-coulda-shoulda-lotta-oughta-betcha-tseasy-etc/296102#296102). This is solely about the acceptability of **ending a sentence** with 'wanna'.

Comment: If you're the pupil's teacher, then this is wrong in academic writing. It may be fine in a character's speech in creative writing, as this is how people speak in real life.

Comment: The pupil is only in year two of an Austrian grammar school, so we're not anywhere near academic writing, even though some of the really motivated kids sometimes use some fancy words they found in their dictionaries in their homework. They have to learn to distinguish between formal and informal forms already, of course. But I do appreciate it if they notice those short forms in pop music etc.

Comment: If I were you, I would read my answer as it is geared to teaching.

Comment: I don’t know who has taught you to write *wanna*, but they have done you a grave disservice. The words in English are written *want to*, and until you learn that, people will not look well upon anything you write, unfairly but inevitably judging you as being tantamount to illiterate in written English.

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] this to actually ask a question.

Comment: @tchrist More than once, I've seen EL&U users, native speakers, mostly American, write "hafta" "gotta" and "ain't" in their *answers*. I don't think anyone accused them of being illiterate.  Besides, it is the pupil who wrote "wanna" and maybe they were writing dialogue, in which case it is quite commendable, the ability to differentiate and imitate formal writing and informal speech is an important skill. The OP is not asking if "wanna" is standard but, it seems to me, about  the word order. I might have written *If you wanna, you can go* but no one has mentioned that possibility.

Comment: @tchrist A non-native English speaker using informal language, [which is used all the time in daily life in the US](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/62057/91248), is being tantamount to being illiterate. Oh, I **should of** known that.

Comment: @MaskedMan You shouldna gone and ran that, seein that I dint say it’s judgers do be  makin a faire judgement; to the contrary. But still it will be one thats made. Moreover, you sir have confuzed the spoken word with the ritten won. Only in eye-dialect duz those sort of stuffs happen.

Comment: @tchrist  Who exactly are you addressing? Me? The OP? The OP said clearly that a student wrote this. And as a teacher, he or she is asking for advice on how to handle it.  The point here is to teach the student the difference between spoken English reflected in writing and written English that is not a reflection of everyday speech "deformations". My goodness!

Comment: notably "wannabe", which is obviously based on "wanna", has found its way into [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wannabee). And it is not marked as a colloquialism ("wanna" is).

Comment: @dlatikay 'dictionaries' apparently equates to M-W, who don't add a 'colloquial' flag to '[wanna](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wanna)': << used for "want to" in informal speech and in representations of such speech >>.

Comment: YouTuber Tom Scott made a [relevant video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkZyZFa5qO0) on this topic not long ago. He also referenced *Aspects of the Theory of Clitics* by Stephen Anderson if anyone want to read more about this.

Answer (score 46):

"Wanna" can, in conversation, be an extremely casual spoken substitute for either "want a" or "want to". "I wanna watch" can either mean "I want a [wrist] watch" or "I want to watch [something]". If "want to" is the meaning intended, then "wanna" can stand anywhere that the more formal phrase can. Except in direct speech, such contractions as "wanna", "gonna", "coulda", "shoulda", etc, have no place in written English that aims for any level of formality above street-talk, and this should, in my opinion, be your concern as a teacher.

Comment: Good point. The "want a" interpretation may be why some feel it needs to be followed by an object.

Comment: When I was a child growing up in South London, the local Cockney dialect had "wanna" (want a) and "wannoo" (want to), the latter mainly used at the end of a sentence, e.g. _Shall we play a game? - I don't wannoo._

Comment: "If "want to" is the meaning intended, then "wanna" can stand anywhere that the more formal phrase can." This I will wholeheartedly disagree with. Consider that "I wanna win the game." sounds markedly better than "Who do you wanna win the game?" If you wanna know more, see https://www.princeton.edu/~browning/wanna.html

Comment: Seems like an opinion piece by a guy at Princeton, that well-known cauldron of street talk.

Comment: "When I was a child growing up in South London, the local Cockney dialect"... is now one with Nineveh and Tyre, I believe.

Comment: The general question about the acceptability of these forms per se is a duplicate. But 'wanna' is a weak form, and weak forms can have different rules. I am here <==> Here I am. I'm here <=/=> *Here I'm. You haven't addressed the specific problem here, and your claim is unsubstantiated and differs from the accepted answer at the duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I also grew up in S(E) London some time ago and recall a similar distinction (though "wanna" as "want to" wasn't unkown).  Visiting your user page I see we're almost neighbours again!

Comment: I use wanna, gotta, and nights often in emails and texts, but as an intentional way to reinforce that I'm not being serious or "of official capacity".

Comment: Probably doesn't bear mention that in a creative writing assignment, such words might be appropriate as part of dialog.

Comment: As I said, direct speech.

Comment: I think the reason it sounds weird is that it really should be "you can go if you want to go", and in many languages, you literally can't break up the infinitive at the end there.

Comment: I've never heard of "wanna" being short for "want a"... the sentence "I wanna watch" means "I want to watch", not "I want a watch" as far as I've ever seen. Where have you seen differently? It'd be great if you could share a link because I can't believe it but I really wanna.

Comment: @Mehrdad - 1. My 66 years as a native English speaker. 2. Oxford Dictionary https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wanna

Answer (score 18):

To be clear, I understand your question to be primarily about **grammar as it applies to pronunciation**, not primarily about spelling, since you said "it **sounds** odd to me". There are certainly grammatical rules about the pronunciation of contractions, weak forms and other things that native English speakers often ignore or just think of as "lazy", "careless" or "sloppy" pronunciation. For example, [Wilson](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/208430/wilson) left a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446903/wanna-at-the-end-of-a-sentence#comment1074577_446910) mentioning the often-discussed linguistic fact that some speakers feel that they cannot use "wanna", or that "wanna" would sound odd, in sentences like "Who do you wanna win the game?", where the subject of the infinitive following "want to" is different from the subject of the verb "want" (the comment links to https://www.princeton.edu/~browning/wanna.html). (I said "some" because my impression is that there may be more variation between speakers in this area than is commonly acknowledged.)

#### "You can go if you wanna" sounds acceptable to me

Maybe some people feel differently, but for me, "wanna" (which I use as a written representation of a particular pronunciation of "want to"; something like [wɑnə] or [wɑɾ̃ə]—this is just an impressionistic transcription, not the result of rigorous phonetic analysis) can stand alone at the end of a sentence just as well as "want to".

Grant Goodall ("[Contraction](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~goodall/contraction.pdf)") seems to describe a few relevant examples, but unfortunately says we don't have very good data about their acceptability:

> Pullum (1997) points out that in principle we should be able to look for such evidence by examining the behavior of *wanna* vs. *want to* in constructions where an overt element in T is required. VP ellipsis (as opposed to null complement anaphora) and VP fronting are two such constructions. Examples of the latter are given in (9).
>
> (9) a. I said I'd wash the dishes, and wash them I did.
>   
> b. *I said I'd help wash the dishes, and wash them I helped.
>
> If *wanna* involves no overt element in the embedded T, we would then
>   predict that (10b) would be worse than (10a).
>
> (10) a. I said I'd feel like climbing the mountain, and climb it I want to.
>   
> b. I said I'd feel like climbing the mountain, and climb it I wanna.
>
> Pullum reports that unfortunately, judgments on sentences like these are so
>   unclear and inconsistent to be of little use (and similar results obtain with examples involving VP ellipsis), so at this point it is an open question whether it is possible to find evidence for or against the presence of *to* in the clause embedded under *wanna*.

If I remember correctly, some linguists have analyzed the "particle" *to* that is used before infinitives in English as an auxiliary. If that analysis is correct, perhaps an analogous example would be the weak pronunciation of *have* in sentences like "You should have" (this weak pronunciation of "have" can be represented in writing as "You should've", which is an informal spelling but which I would say is not considered a misspelling, or as "You should of", which is fairly common in informal contexts, but commonly considered a misspelling).

---

That said, nohat♦'s answer to "[Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction “it's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500)" quotes a section of the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston and Pullum, 2002) which apparently indicates that in the authors' judgement a strong form is needed in a similar sentence:

> *They want me to resign, but I don’t intend* [*to __*].

I'm not sure how to explain the discrepancy between this and my judgement of sentences like "You can go if you wanna". It may be possible that *to* usually has a strong pronunciation in this context, but the contraction *wanna* is an established alternative to *want to.*

"[Another Argument Against Wh-Trace](http://babel.ucsc.edu/Jorge/sag.html)" (Ivan A. Sag) seems to indicate that Pullum has in fact proposed that there is something special about *wanna* and similar words:

> the arbitraryness of the set of verbs to which it applies: *gonna, hafta,* **intenna* (intend to), **lufta* (love to), **meanna* (meant to). Indeed, as Pullum (1997) shows in detail, the optimal analysis of this entire class of verbs involves no rule of 'Wanna Contraction'—wanna forms are morphologically derived. The relevant morpholexical rule applies to seven verbs that select for a single infinitival complement; hence transitive want (which selects for two complements) has no such form. Pullum's analysis explains all phenomena previously discussed in the literature, as well as further data that serve to distinguish his proposal from others that have been advanced.
>
> [...] Pullum, Geoffrey K. 1997. The Morpholexical Nature of English *to*-Contraction. *Language* 73: 79–102.

However, it seems Pullum's account has been criticized by Hans C. Boas ("[You Wanna Consider a Constructional
Approach towards Wanna-contraction?](http://sites.la.utexas.edu/hcb/files/2011/02/ed._Boas-revised-final.pdf)", 2004).

#### The spelling "wanna" is often stigmatized in any context

Another entirely separate issue is the appropriateness in general of the spelling "wanna". As other people have mentioned, many people find the spellings "wanna" and "gonna" inappropriate in any context in any but the most informal writing (I would say it's most likely to be tolerated in online chat rooms or in fictional dialogue). It's never incorrect to write "want to" instead of "wanna", and it's unlikely that any reader will find the spelling "want to" to be overly formal, so you should advise your students to get out of the habit of writing "wanna".

Note that avoiding *spellings* like "wanna" and "gonna" doesn't necessarily mean that you should try to avoid the corresponding pronunciations: I use the pronunciation [wɑnə] or [wɑɾ̃ə] much more often than I use the spelling "wanna". Many English words and phrases have reduced pronunciations ("weak forms") that are not typically indicated in writing, and that native speakers may not even realize they are using. See the Language Log post [Ask Language Log: Writing "gonna" or "going to"](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3219) (Mark Liberman) for some more relevant information.

Comment: Are you implying that there is any self-respecting five-year-old who, when told to go to bed, would say "I don't wanna!"?

Comment: @HotLicks: I don't get your point. What is improbable abut a five-year-old saying "I don't wanna!"? Are you saying it's obvious to you that a five-year-old would instead say "I don't want to!"?

Comment: Yes, 5 year olds I know would be far more likely to say, "sorry Pater, but I am not currently feeling adequately somnolent so I am not yet ready to recline in the arms of Morpheus"

Comment: It's a weak form, and weak forms can have different rules. I am here <==> Here I am. I'm here <=/=> *Here I'm. This is an inadequate answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I thought I made it clear that this answer represents my own intuitions, not some kind of universal rule that I claim to have discovered. There might be variation, but if even one speaker uses a particular pattern, that's evidence that it's not ungrammatical for all speakers. The very vague and general concept of a "weak form" or "contraction" doesn't imply that "wanna" must behave the same way as "I'm".

Comment: Answers that represent one's own intuitions should be kept to comments here, unless you've got equivalent credentials to those of John Lawler.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Why? A native speaker doesn't need any particular credentials to give an acceptability/grammaticality judgement. I'm qualified to say if something is grammatical for me even if I can't explain why.

Comment: Well, we can all go home and leave John Lawler and Mr Ashworth to answer questions concerning usage and slang.

Comment: I have quite a few comments stressing the – I'll use the word _obligation_ – to add supporting evidence to 'answers' on ELU. Here's one: ' [A]nswers which just offer one man's opinion, and no data to back it up (e.g. nGrams or expert opinions or whatever) should be offered as comments, rather than answers proper.'   ( Dan Bron) And moderator tchrist has stated that opinions are inadmissible as answers.

Comment: Ah, good. A better-than-reasonable source. You could have done this without the goading.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I don't think the link answers the question; it just provides some context to the side-question that other answers have brought up of the acceptability of spellings like "wanna", even in cases where the reduced pronunciation can be used in speech. If I find a source that talks about the grammatical question, I'll link it, of course: I just don't think that I need a source like that to post an answer to this question. I think there's a Meta post that discusses some of the nuances of questions like this: I'll try to find a link to it later.

Comment: 'The fact that gonna-type reduction is not available for the verb of motion has long been cited as evidence for the lexicalization  — and maybe grammaticalization — of the aspectual use of "going to".' argues strongly that simplistic answers here should be removed.

Comment: It blows my mind that no one here seems to  have pointed out that wanna is in a class by itself.  Wanna and gonna are grammatically dissimilar while being phonetically similar. And it also blows my mind that very often no distinction is made around here about the grammar of spoken English versus the grammar of written English. Yes, people use it without realizing it. Yes, it can reflect register (or not). Yes, you'd see it in a movie script dialogue and novels and certain transcriptions. People speak how they speak. And linguists can only describe that and the context of utterances.

Comment: I think some of the super-heads here have a problem. It is not feasible to always "prove" something with Ngrams, Googled stuff, academic articles, etc.  For example, one might argue that wanna and gonna both share similar phonetics. wan[t]o and going[t]o, because perhaps o becomes a  in fast speech (na rather than no). "to" often being "ta". (sorry, no IPA for me here). NA is more likely than NO for fast spoken TO. If I were to construct an answer along these lines re wanna and gonna, it could be linguistically valid and yet not be "provable". Though I reckon the TA for TO thing is.

Comment: @Acccumulation But ELU is about usage and documented and peer-reviewed analysis, not punditry. Certainly suggestions made by proficient linguists can be given, but these should not be given as 'answers'.  The edited answer above is vastly superior to the original. // As for the slip you've spotted, you're quite correct. And  your 'Are it should be' should be 'And it should be'.

Comment: I don't believe the question was about pronunciation; it was about writing....anyway, this answer is fine.

Answer (score 9):

It's just a short way of saying 'want to', so it doesn't need something to follow after it as it can stand alone. It isn't formal English.

Comment: Ah, but never use an "a" to end a sentence wi.

Comment: This isn’t quite true. _Wanna_ is a contracted form of _want to_, yes, but contractions don’t necessarily act like their uncontracted forms. To me, one of the differences between _want to_ and _wanna_ is precisely that the latter only occurs with an immediately following object clause, making the example noted in the question very awkward and unnatural.

Comment: I see no difference between ending the sentence with _want to_ or _wanna_ (apart from formality).

Comment: It's a weak form, and weak forms can have different rules. I am here <==> Here I am. I'm here <=/=> *Here I'm.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth please provide supporting evidence in your comments that colloquial and nonstandard English remarks/speech cannot end with "wanna".

Comment: @Mari-Lou A No. That's why they're entered as 'comments' not 'answers'. They lack the support I consider necessary for answers. As do many 'answers' here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but you're downvoting nearly all the answers based on your explanation. What has "Here I'm" got to do with "wanna"? DV if you must because the answers lack supporting evidence but not because you say they are wrong.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I'm saying that in this answer there is a use of  false logic, an unjustified argument from analogy, not that the conclusion is necessarily incorrect. And that other answers to date [this comment has been corrected for a typo 10 hours after the original] don't address the terminal usage OP actually asks about. You know, M-L, you're convincing me that I'm flogging a dead horse here. And I've certainly better things to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can go if you want to [implied to go].

[see explanation below]
A standard, full-sentence in English would be:

You can go if you want to go.

You can go if you wanna. [colloquial only, spoken only, never in formal writing]

The TAKEAWAY: ***Spoken versus written English***

In spoken English, one does not have to repeat a predicate from the main clause in many cases, when the predicate after the *to* would be the same phrase as in the main clause's predicate. This is especially true of verbs of these verbs: want, wish need, have and expect. This has a technical name which I cannot recall now, but they are basically verbs expressing volition of some kind.

You can stop now ***if you have to*** [stop now].
They will arrive late **if they want to** [arrive late]
You will find out if **you need to** [find out].
He works late whenever **he wishes to** [work late].
Don't leave early unless you expect them to [leave early].

It is perfectly fine to speak this way, and every English speaker does, however, in a formal written text one would not:

- The armies battled for months along the river though their respective generals did not expect them to.

There are those who assert that that sentence is OK. Nevertheless, were it my thesis I was writing, I would write:

- The armies battled for months along the river though their respective generals did not expect ***them to do so.***

In order to cut down on unwieldy sentences, one can substitute "to do so" (or say so, etc.) to avoid unwieldy repetition. However, the repetition is always  implied.

One last word: A honest linguist recognizes that "wanna" exists. And linguists do not care about whether some grammarian establishment thinks its "acceptable" or "not".

[Unfortunately, the bolding and italics here won't work for me.]

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with "You can go if you want to"

Comment: @Mitch  standard means long form, if you will. It doesn't mean there's anything wrong it it. Surely, if you had read my entire explanation, that would have been clear to you? Anyway, I clarified it further....

Comment: I think you are mixing the 'don't end a proposition with a sentence' Latin rule with "standard".  In formal written English, implied words are fine.  "You can stop now if you have to stop now" (regardless of the 'can'/'have to' mismatch) is just awkward.

Comment: No, I am not mixing up anything at all. It is a fact about speech (utterances) in English that I have ***described***. Nowhere am I prescriptive. "wanna" is a speech thing. It has nothing to do with not ending a sentence with a preposition. It is about English allowing non-repetition of the main  verb and allowing the preposition in speech to be there "hang out there" as it were. But it also occurs in utterances: He doesn't wanna go (spoken). And it has zero to do with spelling except for the spelling mirroring how it is said.

Answer (score 1):

*Wanna* is normally considered a nonstandard spelling.  It’s a phonetic spelling of a common pronunciation in American English, but a transcript of someone who pronounced “want to” or “want a” that way would normally correct the spelling, like it would normally leave out *uh* and *um*.  If you saw somebody’s dialogue spelled that way in a novel, the connotation would be that the character is childish.  So I would suggest you teach your students to avoid that spelling.

There are some people who also think it’s an error to end a sentence with *want to*, because they believe a preposition should not be “stranded” without an explicit object.  (I have also heard an older shibboleth against ending a sentence with a preposition, but that appears to be completely defunct.)  I personally consider that a hypercorrection: that rule was made up by analogy with Latin grammar centuries ago, and has no basis in either the spoken language or the usage of many of the best English writers.  Winston Churchill made fun of how comically stilted following this rule can sound when he said that ending a sentence with a preposition was something “up with which I shall not put.”

I would take out my red pen and correct “wanna” to “want to.”

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. i'm sure the writer meant "wanna", not "want to".  The OP did not seem to understand that the two are equivalent, even if "wanna" is not formal standard English .

Comment: Well, the thing about want to, need to and have to is that they are an integral part of English. And very much used in speech. And thus, very much used at the end of sentences. That has nothing to do with writing, of course.

Comment: @J.Taylor Thanks for the welcome! The OP was quoting a student who wrote, “You can go if you wanna,” so in that context, the student meant, “want to.” Some of the other answers assert that the grammar should also be corrected, to “want to go,” and I disagree. But a teacher should be aware that some people do consider sentences that end in *to* incorrect.

Comment: @sumelic It’s a phonetic spelling. Our last two presidents have frequently pronounced the word that way, but it’s rarely transcribed that way. One exception: the CBS News transcription of its interview with then-President-Elect Donald Trump on Nov. 13, 2016 quotes him saying, “I'd wanna see, you know, he may have had very good reasons for doing what he did,” and “I wanna do the job. We have some great generals.” A few sources transcribe Barack Obama’s comment, “If folks want to pop off,” as, “If folks wanna pop off,” but not many.

Comment: @sumelic Edited to more accurately describe the rule that some people have against that usage.

Comment: @Davislor the current president uses 'wanna' [in 'writing'](https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/552686257177124867?lang=en).

Comment: @JJJ Only when he’s limited to 140 (or now 280) characters.

Comment: @Davislor you're right, bad example, he's actually quoting someone who's quoting him. He actually writes the full version most of the time. See [here for a full overview and proper search](http://www.trumptwitterarchive.com/archive). But then you can't really attack him on Twitter: [He is "the best 140 character writer in the world"](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/267286471172562944).

Comment: @JJJ Well, he’s certainly the most-followed and discussed.

Answer (score 1):

While I always thought it's incorrect, a misspelling, it is actually listed by multiple dictionaries. The definitions listed are (some only list the first, this will be indicated below):

> 1:short form of **want to**
>
> 2:short form of **want a**

More interesting, I think, is to compare what else the different dictionaries say about it. A quick overview:

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wanna) lists it as *not standard*.

[Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wanna) lists it as *informal*.

[Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wanna) only lists the first definition and emphasises that the term is informal.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wanna) only lists the first definition and emphasises that it's spelled as it is pronounced and that the word is informal.

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wanna) lists it as informal.

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wanna) only lists the first definition and describes it as *short form* and *informal*.

Comment: This addresses the general question (which is a duplicate) not the specific one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth consider this a partial answer. If you think the question is a duplicate, please vote for it using the appropriate flag, I cannot really help with that.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. But all the answers to date are answers to the less specific question 'Is _wanna_ [etc] acceptable?' (a question asked and answered before).

Comment: It is not clear to me what you think the "more specific" question is. People have said that "wanna" is acceptable and that it is also acceptable at the end of a sentence, with nothing following. What else is needed?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth are you saying that I am not even providing a partial answer?

Comment: I'm saying that the question _you_'re answering here was asked and answered years ago, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220300/acceptability-of-gonna-wanna).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sorry Edwin, that question has since been closed. My answer stands as a partial answer to this question. Also, that question specifically asks about a business setting, so at best my answer would be a partial one there.

Comment: @EdwinA - [Another related question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296051/kinda-sorta-coulda-shoulda-lotta-oughta-betcha-tseasy-etc/).

Answer (score 0):

I am about to disagree with what has been posted before and won't even be able to cite references.  I know that spells ill luck, but at least I'll give a reasoning.

"wanna" is an informal contraction.  It does not stand at the same level as "I'm" or "I'd" which are perfectly valid non-colloquial speech.  It is a half-phonetic spelling of quite colloquial speech.

"You can go if you wanna." is incongruous in the complexity and order of its elements, and the place of the contraction is at the end of an utterance where it doesn't serve a purpose in not distracting from what's following it.

It's similar to "This is either not going to break, or it's.": the abbreviation makes breathing and thinking room for a continuation the absence of which is irritating.

More coherent would be "You wanna go, just go.": not only does the "wanna" contraction have an actual infinitive following it, the whole abbreviated conditional falls more in line with the overall informality.

Now "wanna" in itself is not fit for written speech but of course will serve as a transcription of colloquial speech.  Colloquial speech as a transcription of an imagined or factual utterance is not bound to grammaticality or rhyme or reason.  Flagging "character incoherence" on the writings of a young person would be excessive.

So I don't see that you have lots of options other than flagging "wanna" as improper speech/grammar/spelling irrespective of the particular strangeness of this particular use.

Comment: Intersting. It seems there are some people for whom sentence-final wanna is acceptable and others for whom it isn't. This could be regional or age/class related.

Comment: Also, colloquial speech is just as bound to rules of grammar as any other form of language (possibly different from the rules of the written language, but rules all the same).

Comment: It's unclear.  Are you saying that "You can go if you want to" is "improper"?

Comment: +1 for actually addressing (in your 3rd-5th paras) the question asked, viz  "why is sentence-final 'wanna' odd?".  (It seems odd to me too, if the infinitive verb is not explicit.)

Comment: wanna is most definitely not a contraction: a contraction is: don't; doesn't aren't; isn't, wouldn't. etc. etc. It is an informal truncation, if anything. wanna is a written form that mirrors the spoken idiom. Even the more educated speakers might not hear themselves saying it when they speak fast....